# How to rotate text in single cell in Pages on Mac?

Tags: macos, pages

This is what I have now:

[image]

And this is what I would like to make:

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Any updates to this 3 years later?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I have found to do this, (and probably the same as you have done to illustrate the question), is to insert a text box or shape and rotate the shape/textbox by 90 degrees. Probably not the solution you are after but a barely workable workaround

Comment: It is not the solution, indeed.